# Triggering googletest error on EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ even when numbers are within 4 decimal places

Tags: c++, floating-point, googletest

I'm creating unit tests for a program that performs floating point computations in C++. Throughout the unit test file, I've been using EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ successfully, even when the floating point numbers are not exactly the same: some successful tests have had results that are ~.00000001 off without triggering an error. This makes sense to me, as the documentation I found [here](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/au-googletestingframework/#list9) states that no errors are triggered as long as results "tally up to four decimal places."

However, for a few specific computations, google test is returning an error, even when the numbers are within four decimal places. This is the test in question:

```
EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(test_Calc->result, 0.00714787);
```

And this is the error returned:

```
Expected: test_Calc->result
  Which is: 0.0071478747
  To be equal to: 0.00714787
```

Not only does this tally to 4 decimal places, it tallies to 8 decimal places, so I'm unsure what's going wrong. Am I wrong in my assumption about decimal places for EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ, or could something else be going wrong? I'd prefer not having to using EXPECT_NEAR for only this specific test.

The variable test_Calc->result is a float, and I've tried inputting the expected value as a float variable instead: nothing seems to work.

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: `0.00714787` is not of a type float.

Comment: @user253751 I added a specific question, thanks.

Comment: @vahancho What do you mean by this? I've also tried writing the test in the following way: "float test1 = 0.00714787; EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(test_Calc->result, test1);", which doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What does `0.00714787f` give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IBM docs got it wrong. The `EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ` macro requires the values to be "almost equal" or, strictly defined, within 4 units in the last place. [Google Test docs on floating point comparison](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#floating-point) give a short explanation of ULPs, with references to [more reading](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

If you want values to be equal within 4 decimal places, use

```
EXPECT_NEAR(test_Calc->result, 0.00714787, 0.0001);
```